# Windows Service created in C# doing LOAD DATA INFILE: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, mysql

Same is working Windows API but giving problem in windows service....

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:/WS/Dump/FInalMainFile01_28Jan2021.csv' INTO TABLE xyz FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'  IGNORE 1 LINES ;
```

```
2021-07-09 18:16:27.0745 ERROR System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
```

Comment: This exception call stack is just .NET Framework code. What's the full call stack, including your code?

Comment: What does `File.WriteAllText` have to do with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`? Please show all your code.

Answer (score 0):

`'E:/WS/Dump/FInalMainFile01_28Jan2021.csv'` isn't a valid Windows (DOS) path name, just like the error message says. The separator on Windows is not `/`, it is `\`.

You need `'E:\WS\Dump\FInalMainFile01_28Jan2021.csv'`. And if you're handling a string constant in a C# program you need to escape the `\` characters.

```
const string path = "E:\\WS\\Dump\\FInalMainFile01_28Jan2021.csv";
```

Comment: I tried with the given solution  see the path "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Default Company Name\\YRSKServicetoUpload\\Dump\\usa 100 sample (1).csv"  But still it is giving me same error....This related to some permission or need to add some administrator privilege in service...  Please help...